# How does my screen look to a mantis shrimp?

Tags: visible-light, perception

As a human, I have one 3 color receptors that activate somewhere around the colors red, green, and blue. However, as [this very cool infographic displays](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/mantis_shrimp), a mantis shrimp has 16 different color receptors!

It is no coincidence that the screen I'm looking at is composed of tiny dots of only three colors, red, green, and blue. This is sufficient for me, but dreadfully lacking for a mantis shrimp I suspect. But I don't know... I've never been a mantis shrimp!

How can I imagine what my computer screen must look like to mantis shrimp. Is there any analogy that might help?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1982/2451

Comment: This seems better suited for [Cognitive Science](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/) than physics (to the extent that it is answerable at all, which it may not be). After all, it is a question about *perception*.